# Extract text from multiple tweets in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

I have extracted 1000 tweets that mention my internship company. So, I received the data in JSON format. Now, I am trying to extract the text for each 1000 tweets of the JSON

Since the JSON is stored as notepad, so I used require('fs') and also readFileSync because of synchronous actions

```
const fs=require('fs')

var lineTNB = fs.readFileSync('mentionTNB.json','utf8',function(err,data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
var i;
for (i=0;i<lineTNB.length;i++){
        console.log(lineTNB[i].text);
    }
```

The expected values would be
"text": "string1234"
"text": "string7682"

The actual values: 
undefined
undefined

Comment: `readFileSync` is synchronous as you said, so why are you passing it a callback function?

Comment: also, assuming your callback would work... you are not returning the parsed object.

Comment: I am quite new in javascript, I have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still want it to be sync:

```
var res = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('mentionTNB.json', 'utf8'));

console.log(res)
```

If you actually meant you want it async with callback:

```
var res = fs.readFile('mentionTNB.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  return JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: both of these gives me error. 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 2775
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\user\TNB Twitter\extractTwitter.js:5:17
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)